# Why I can´t perform a left mouse click?

Tags: swift, macos, qmouseevent

I am creating a software that moves the mouse cursor and performs left and right clicks. I got the cursor moving but I can´t perform left clicks. What am I doing wrong?

```
let point = CGPoint(x:366, y:528) // Random point
    self.moveCursor(point: point)

    // click mouse
    let eventMouseDown = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: 
      .leftMouseDown, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton:.left)
    eventMouseDown?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)

    // release mouse
    let eventMouseUp = CGEvent(mouseEventSource: nil, mouseType: 
      .leftMouseUp, mouseCursorPosition: point, mouseButton: .left)
     eventMouseUp?.post(tap: .cghidEventTap)
```

Comment: Is App Sandbox switched off?

Comment: Yes, and still not working. It should perform click in the designated CGPoint, but it doesn´t.

Comment: Are you running the Mojave beta?

Comment: No, high Sierra V. 10.13.4

Comment: I tried your code and it works for me. I removed `self.moveCursor(point: point)`. Is the code executed on the main thread?

Comment: It is working! I discovered that the App Sandboxing in the entitlements file was on YES. I changed it to NO, and worked as expected! Thanks a lot for your help!!